# Accessing the data used in .load()

Tags: jquery, load

When using the `.load()` method to load some external php/HTML, how do you access the data in the external file?

Say the first file is 'index.php' and it contains something like;

```
$('#contentContainer').load('productContent.php',{param1:'data.xml'});
```

inside 'productContent.php' I want to be able to parse different XML files by passing the XML filename as shown. However, I don't know how to get access to 'param1' from within 'productContent.php'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be there under

```
$_REQUEST['param1'];
```

**Edit:** On the server you need a file called `productContent.php` like this:

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['param1'];
?>
```

**Edit2:** If you are writing JavaScript in your PHP file (which I think is a bad idea, JavaScript files should generally be kept away from the generated HTML) then you'd do something like this:

```
$(this).ready(function () {
  var d = <?php echo $_REQUEST['param1']; ?>;
});
```

But this is pretty messy.

Comment: But if I do this:

 $(this).ready(function()
 {
   var d = $_REQUEST['param1'];
 });

I get a "$_REQUEST is not defined" error (Firefox:Firebug)

Comment: You said you wanted to access `param1` in the external file - I assume you mean in the PHP file. That's JavaScript code in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant access param1 in the javascript/jquery in the external file.

Comment: @neilbaldwin Oh, there's JavaScript embedded in the PHP?

Comment: OK, thanks for your help Skilldrick. I'll mark this as answered and go back to learning some more. :)